# How to read tweets for a particular user with out login

Tags: iphone, twitter

My client wants twitter integration in my iPhone app in this way that User can read tweets for a particular user without login into the app.

Comment: For example I want to read tweets from twitter in my app.but user don't to login into twitter.

Comment: u can show tweets in your app. but u hv to login to twitter within your app..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of twitter API requests require authentications.
But some public data available without login.
For example you can receive user timeline (one seen when you view a user's profile on twitter.com) as json string with request:
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=twitterapi&count=2

find more at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api#timelines

Answer (score 0):

http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa